# How to use AFNetworking frame work with json Login with my own api i have tokens to pass but i dont now how to use those

Tags: ios, iphone, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

How do i use AFNetworking Framework to authenticate and login in to my IPhone application i have my own api and have some tokens like this X-User-Email,X-User-Token. i dont know what i have to do with this tokens somke one help me exactly what i have to do

i am using some code searching many methods but am not getting exactly did i have to do anything more

i have given code like this but i dont know where to give tokens

```
{  
  if([[userNameTF text] isEqualToString:@""] || [[passWordTF text] isEqualToString:@""] ) {
        [self alertStatus:@"Please enter both Username and Password" :@"Login Failed!"];
    } else {
        NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"user[email]=%@&user[password]=%@",[userNameTF text],[passWordTF text] ];
        NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://secure.sample.in/login"];

        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        //[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
        if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonData);
            NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
            NSLog(@"%d",success);
            if(success == 1)
            {
                NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];

            } else {

                NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [jsonData objectForKey:@"error_message"];
                [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
            }

        } else {
            if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Login Failed!"];
        }
    }
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
    [self alertStatus:@"Login Failed." :@"Login Failed!"];
}
```

Comment: You mean you have headers that you need to set? Why not set them like the other headers you have?

Comment: I dont now i i have tokens for authentication and a secret key and i have to create a login page i dont know what to do. help me please

Answer (score 0):

Request would like this using `AFNetworking` :

```
//Create parameter dictionary
NSDictionary *dictParameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:strEmailHere,@"email",strPasswordHere,@"password",nil];

//create post request 
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
//pass serializer may be http or json
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]; //[AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *apiRequest = [manager POST:strURL parameters:dictNewParameter success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{

}
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{

}];
```

Comment: Stremailhere in that place I have to put X-User-Email ?

Comment: And I also have user[email] is that need to use